# Zakat payment inquire

Tags: zakat

I purchase land for resale in future by 10-15 years and every year value of land is increasing...  for example: last year if the value of land is Rupees 500000/- which paid zakat @ 2.5%  and this year it is increase to rupees 600000/-
So please advise me shall I pay zakat in rupees 600000/- or increase in the value of land by rupees 100000/-

Comment: I think its today's price

Answer (score 1):

In the Name of Allah, The Most Gracious, The Most Merciful.

When you pay zakat, you have to pay 2.5% of that which you own. So if you have 100,000 dollars, you have to pay 2,500 dollars AT LEAST. You can pay more if you want, but the **extra** you give is considered as "sadaqa", not as zakat.

As for your question; you have to give 2.5% of all your wealth **the moment you give zakat.** So if you decided to give zakat tomorrow, and everything you own is worth one million (right now), then you have to give 2.5% of what it's worth **now**, so 25 Thousand (of one million).

In your case, you have to pay 2.5% of 600k Rupees. So yeah, you always have to take today's price.

I'm not a scholar, so if someone disagrees with me, and comes with proof that I'm wrong, please share it, so that we may benefit.

Allah knows best.